# Amazon AWS RDS - How to Programmatically Create a MS SQL Database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, connection-string

I've created an Amazon AWS RDS instance running MS SQL. I've successfully been able to programmatically create a database in C# using:

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<public-ip-name>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<userid>;PWD=<pwd>;");
myConn.Open();
string str = "CREATE DATABASE contacts";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, I haven't been able to make a more complex connection string work:

```
        str = "CREATE DATABASE contacts ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = Contacts_Data, " +
            @"FILENAME = 'c:\contacts.mdf', " +
            "SIZE = 4MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
            "LOG ON (NAME = Contacts_Log, " +
            @"FILENAME = 'c:\contacts.ldf', " +
            "SIZE = 1MB, " +
            "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
            "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
```

The error (5) seems to complain that C:\ can't be written to. Perhaps it doesn't exist?  If I omit FILENAME, an error complains that I omitted it. What is the correct value for FILENAME? It appears that FILENAME must specify an existing file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coded jtseng's answer in C#

```
static string GetDBPath(SqlConnection myConn, string db = "master")
{
  string sqlstr = "USE " + db + "; EXEC sp_helpfile";
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, myConn);
  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
  reader.Read();
  string filename = reader["filename"].ToString();
  string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
  return directory;
}
```

called via:

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<public ip>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<userid>;PWD=<pwd>;");
myConn.Open();
string dbPath = GetDBPath(myConn); // default db is master
```

Comment: The sql command reveals that the default drive is D:\ and the default directory is D:\RDSDBDATA\DATA. Ah, so that's why FILENAME = 'c:\contacts.mdf' was failing.

Comment: Do you know if there is some documentation on the default directory (`D:\RDSDBDATA\DATA`)? I wonder if it could change in the future or whatever...

Answer (score 1):

To find out which directory you *can* create databases in:

1. Create a database DB1 the simple way.
2. Find out where the database files are located:

   USE DB1
   GO
   EXEC sp_helpfile
   GO
3. Create a database with the files in that directory.

Comment: Yeah but ... How can I create a directory on a Amazon AWS RDS MS SQL instance?

Comment: @BSalita My bad. I don't think you get to do the file system management yourself. Nor are you suppose to create databases with TSQL. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html for how you're suppose to do it.

Comment: I don't see any information in your links that show how to create or drop a database. They show how to create or terminate an instance which is not relevant. I can't find any Amazon RDS API to create or drop a database. Anyone?

Comment: @BSalita Good point. Sorry for being so sloppy. It appears that you are stuck with the directory structure in AWS. If you still have some time to play with me, I have updated my answer with how to find which directory you can create your database in.