# Amazon AWS RDS - How to Programmatically Create a MS SQL Table in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, create-table

I've create an Amazon AWS RDS MS SQL instance. I want to programmatically create a database followed by a table. I've created a connection using a connection string that has no "Database=" parameter. First I create the database, next I want to create a table using the same connection. How can I specify that the table is to be created using the newly created database? I know I can close the connection and reopen with a "Database=" parameter but I would like to create the table without an additional close/open.

Here is the sql command that I'm using to create a table. Is there a way to specify the database name "Contacts" using a sql command?

```
CREATE TABLE ContactDetails (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question ... the solution is to prepend USE  to the CREATE TABLE command:

```
USE Contacts; CREATE TABLE ContactDetails (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

I have not found an Amazon RDS API call to create or drop a table. Anyone?

Comment: For creating a database programmatically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410121/amazon-aws-rds-how-to-programmatically-create-a-ms-sql-database-in-c/17425453#17425453

Answer (score -2):

Under 'Connect to a database' you see the option to 'select or enter a database name'.  Just enter the name of the new database and click ok. It will create a new DB and from there you can right click on 'Tables' and add a table.

[image]

Comment: I want to PROGRAMMATICALLY create a table using C#. Hello?